# Getting exception org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be org.apache.hadoop.hive.serd2.io.TimestampWritable

Tags: hadoop, hive

Source hive table column is string type which has string date with timestamp .
Target hive table column having timestamp datatype .

while loading source hive to target hive table getting text can not be timestampWritable.

Source String date -- `2021-10-15 15:31:21.000000-05:00`
Above date casted as - `2021-10-15 15:31:21.0`   ( source date casted using unix_timestamp then from_unixtime)

Comment: How are you loading data?